# API Request returns correctly, but is null in the callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, request

I am using npm Express and Request modules to obtain movie information via an API:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");

app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    console.log(getBody("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=The+Shining&page=1&apikey=myKey"));
});

function getBody(requestString){
    request(requestString, function(error, response, body){
        return body;
    };
}
```

I removed error checking on the request here for the sake of readability.

Within the request, logging "body" shows that the request did return proper JSON. However, when I return to app.get, the value of the logging is undefined.

Is it not possible to return this value to app.get's callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` is an async function, so you need to use one of the many techniques (callback, promise etc) to return the data successfully.

Here's an example with a callback:

```
app.get("/results", function(req, res) {
  getBody(endpoint, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

function getBody(endpoint, callback) {
  request(endpoint, function(error, response, body) {
    callback(body);
  });
}
```

And an example using a promise:

```
app.get("/results", function(req, res) {
  getBody(endpoint).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

function getBody(endpoint, callback) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(endpoint, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) reject('Request failed');
      resolve(body);
    });  
  });
}
```